# How to get the visible child controls when scrolling a parent control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

[image]

My code when adding the Labels to a Panel:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To 50
        Panel1.Controls.Add(New Label With {.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle, .AutoSize = False, .Visible = True, .Text = i.ToString, .Width = 50, .Dock = DockStyle.Left})
    Next
End Sub
```

Now, how to get the visible Labels when the Panel is scrolling, maybe in the `Panel1.Scroll` event?

```
 Private Sub Panel1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Scroll
    If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll Then
        'HOW ?????
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [Rectangle.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.contains?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Rectangle.Contains);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2) and [Rectangle.IntersectWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Drawing.Rectangle.IntersectsWith);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) methods to determine whether a Control is fully or partially visible inside a container.

Using `Rectangle.Contains`, you can determine if the rectangle defined by a Control's `Bounds` is fully included in the rectangle defined by the Container's `ClientRectangle`.

Using `Rectangle.IntersectWith`, you can determine if it's only partially visible.

This method allows you to specify what Controls to consider: the Controls that are fully visible or just partially visible inside their Container Control (a Panel, in this case).

In the example:

```
Dim visibleLabels = GetVisibleControls(CType(sender, Control), e.NewValue, False)
```

will return a collection of Controls (Labels, in this case) that are fully visible inside the Panel1 container.

```
Private Sub Panel1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Scroll
    If e.ScrollOrientation = ScrollOrientation.HorizontalScroll Then
        Dim visibleLabels = GetVisibleControls(CType(sender, Control), e.NewValue, False)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetVisibleControls(container As Control, ScrollPosition As Integer, allowPartial As Boolean) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Dim ctrls = New List(Of Control)
    Dim rect As Rectangle = container.ClientRectangle

    For Each ctl As Control In container.Controls
        If allowPartial Then
            If ctl.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rect) Then
                ctrls.Add(ctl)
            End If
        Else
            If rect.Contains(ctl.Bounds) Then
                ctrls.Add(ctl)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return ctrls
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the visible labels when scrolling. You have to look which label is in the `ClientRectangle` of `Panel1`. This is the viewable area of `Panel1`.
In your question it is not clear what you want to do with the visible labels. Let's assume you want to write the names of the viewable labels in `Textbox1` while scrolling `Panel1`. You can do that with the following code:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Scroll
    Dim myBounds as Rectangle = Panel1.ClientRectangle
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    For Each control in Panel1.Controls
        Dim label as Label = CType(control,Label)
        if label.Location.X > myBounds.X And label.Location.X<myBounds.Width Or label.Location.X+label.Width>myBounds.X AND label.Location.X+label.Width<myBounds.Width Then
            TextBox4.Text +=  CType( control,Label).Text + vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Notice that the above approach lists all partly viewable labels. If you just want to list all labels which are fully visible you just change the code:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Scroll
    Dim myBounds as Rectangle = Panel1.ClientRectangle
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    For Each control in Panel1.Controls
        Dim label as Label = CType(control,Label)
        if label.Location.X > myBounds.X And label.Location.X<myBounds.Width AND label.Location.X+label.Width>myBounds.X AND label.Location.X+label.Width<myBounds.Width Then
            TextBox4.Text +=  CType( control,Label).Text + vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```